# What is the proper way to check for more derived types in a generic collection?

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I am writing a dialog module for my XNA game as a learning project. I have been using the accepted answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/what-is-the-logic-behind-dialog-trees) as a guide.

Every `ILink` contains an `ICollection<ICondition>`, which is used to determine whether or not all conditions have been met in order to make a particular dialog link appear as an option:

```
public interface INode
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    ICollection<ILink> Links { get; set; }
}

public interface ILink
{
    INode Target { get; set; }
    IScript Script { get; set; }
    ICollection<string> Text { get; set; }
    ICollection<ICondition> Conditions { get; set; }
}

public interface IScript { void Execute(); }
public interface ICondition { bool Evaluate(); }
```

Based on this, it was apparent that each type of comparison I wanted to make would have to be its own class:

```
public class EntityHasItem : ICondition
{
    public IEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public IItem Item { get; set; }
    public bool Evaluate() { return Entity.Inventory.Contains(Item); }
}
```

Or

```
public class QuestHasFlag : ICondition
{
    public IQuest Quest { get; set; }
    public IFlag Flag { get; set; }
    public bool Evaluate() { return Quest.Flags.Contains(Flag); }
}
```

How can I check what type each element of `INode.Conditions` is? I might make an editor, or provide feedback, for example. Because of the generic collection, it will always return with ICondition (which is the most common derived type), but it only exposes Evaluate(), which isn't much help here.

My first thought was to use reflection to get a list of types that were derived from `ICondition`, then compare that list against every element of the collection, but that seems like overkill. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you need to know the type? You should just call Evaluate on all of them. `Conditions.All(Evaluate);`

Comment: Once a node has been set up, it becomes impossible to view or change the conditions unless I cast it, which is a "no-no" according to @Jeremy's answer below.

Comment: Thats right, is that a problem? You can always override ToString() (or add a "Display" function to the interface) to "view" the conditions. I guess I'm not sure how to answer, since as you said, you shouldn't be doing this...

Comment: Like I said, if I made an editor, being able to adjust the objects would be very important. Or would this be done in another way? ie, to/from JSON, the editor makes it look pretty, and the game itself wraps it all up into interfaces that nobody needs to know about?

Comment: I'm going to say it should be done another way (see my answer). BTW, you may consider using XML instead of JSON (this isn't a web page after all :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this, violation of an interface (by downcasting) should only be done with great care and good reason.

There are two use cases you mentioned for wanting to do this, viewing and editing.

For viewing, the solution is simple. Either override `.ToString()` to get the information you need, or if you need "pretty" output, create an interface function `DrawInfo` to do this display for you (passing parameters as necessary, like an area of the screen to draw to).

For editing, you'll want a `DrawDialog` function. Like the `DrawInfo` function, this could take an "area" parameter. Assuming this dialog can manage its own UI controls (buttons and the like) you're done. This, by the way, would be analogous to having a class return a `UserControl` in WPF/Winforms to do the same thing.

Having these in the interface ensures that every derived class has it (invoking a method via reflection is not safe or fun!) and you don't need to worry about the types at runtime, polymorphism takes care of everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can call the `GetType()` method on any .NET object.  This will return the actual type of the object (EntityHasItem, QuestHasFlag, etc).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

for example:

```
foreach(var condition in type.Conditions)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(condition.GetType().FullName);
}
```

Comment: You can do this, but very rarely *should* you do this. Its hard to tell if the OP has a valid use case for this or not.

Comment: yeah every time you have to do this it is a sign that there is a better way of designing it

Comment: okay okay-  I should have asked the OP more questions about what they were trying to accomplish like @BradleyDotNET.  Please don't crucify me ;)